# unable to display the calculation on the graphs in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am unable to display the calculation in tableau ( in the example provided below is the percentage calculation) . Let me know what is the procedure to be followed to display the calculation on the graph irrespective of its size. PFB Screenshot of the graph. The link to image is https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WMoM.png

Answer (score 0):

Under the label select "Allow labels to overlap other marks"

This will force tableau to show all calculation values.